# Disable/Avoid an advice execution in AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Suppose I have an aspect

```
public aspect Hack {

pointcut authHack(String user, String pass): call(* Authenticator.authenticate(String,String)) && args(user,pass);

boolean around(String user, String pass): authHack(user,pass) {
    out("$$$ " + user + ":" + pass + " $$$");
    return false;
}

}
```

The `Authenticator.authenticate` method is important. The hack intercepts calls to this method.

**Is it possible to write a second aspect that cancels/disables the `authHack` advice of Hack aspect?**

I can catch the execution of the `around authHack` advice, but if I want to continue the authentication i need to call `Authenticator.authenticate` again and this creates an infinite loop..

Comment: Great question. To those reading, Yaneeve gives a fine answer but don't stop there. The answer kreigaex gives makes it real and takes it one step further.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order simulate your situation, I had written the following Authenticator code:

```
public class Authenticator {

    public boolean authenticate(String user, String pass) {
        System.out.println("User: '" + user + "', pass: '" + pass + "'");
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

        boolean status = authenticator.authenticate("Yaneeve", "12345");
        System.out.println("Status: '" + status + "'");
    }

}
```

output is:

```
User: 'Yaneeve', pass: '12345'
Status: 'true'
```

I added your Hack aspect:

```
public aspect Hack {

    pointcut authHack(String user, String pass): call(* Authenticator.authenticate(String,String)) && args(user,pass);

    boolean around(String user, String pass): authHack(user,pass) {
        System.out.println("$$$ " + user + ":" + pass + " $$$");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the output is:

```
$$$ Yaneeve:12345 $$$
Status: 'false'
```

**Now for the solution:**

I had created the following HackTheHack aspect:

```
public aspect HackTheHack {

    declare precedence: "HackTheHack", "Hack";

    pointcut authHack(String user, String pass): call(* Authenticator.authenticate(String,String)) && args(user,pass);

    boolean around(String user, String pass): authHack(user,pass) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            Class<?> klass = Class.forName("Authenticator");
            Object newInstance = klass.newInstance();
            Method authMethod = klass.getDeclaredMethod("authenticate", String.class, String.class);
            status = (Boolean) authMethod.invoke(newInstance, user, pass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

Output is again:

```
User: 'Yaneeve', pass: '12345'
Status: 'true'
```

*This only works if the original pointcut in Hack aspect was 'call' and not 'execution' as execution actually catches reflection.*

Explanation:

I used Aspect precedence to invoke HackTheHack before Hack:

```
declare precedence: "HackTheHack", "Hack";
```

I then used reflection (note can and should be optimized to reduce the repeating lookup of the method) to simply invoke the original method without the Hack around advice. This had been made possible due to 2 things:

1. the authHack pointcut: `pointcut authHack(String user, String pass): call(* Authenticator.authenticate(String,String)) && args(user,pass);` uses  (in both aspects) `call()` instead of `execution()`
2. I did not call `proceed()` in HackTheHack

I would like to refer you to [Manning's AspectJ in Action, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/laddad2) which had put me on the right track with:

> 6.3.1 Ordering of advice
>
> As you’ve just seen, with multiple aspects present in a system, pieces of advice in the  different aspects can
>   often apply to a single join point. When this happens, AspectJ  uses
>   the following precedence rules to determine the order in which the
>   advice is  applied. Later, you’ll see how to control precedence:
>
> 1 The aspect with higher precedence executes its before advice on a join
>   point before the aspect with lower precedence.
>
> 2 The aspect with higher precedence executes its after advice on a join point after the
>   aspect with lower precedence.
>
> 3 The around advice in the higher-precedence aspect encloses the around advice  in the
>   lower-precedence aspect. This kind of arrangement allows the higher-
>   precedence aspect to control whether the lower-precedence advice will
>   run by  controlling the call to proceed(). If the higher-precedence
>   aspect doesn’t call  proceed() in its advice body, not only will the
>   lower-precedence aspects not  execute, but the advised join point also
>   won’t execute.

Comment: Very good answer. I have some questions, though: 1) is `declare precedence: "HackTheHack", "Hack";` necessary 2) can I set `HackTheHack` to preceed ALL aspects? 3) What if the Hack used `execution`?

Comment: @elmes thanks :). to answer your questions. 1) YES. 2) I think so... the following declaration worked for me, try it: declare precedence: "HackTheHack", "*"; 3) It wouldn't work. If HackTheHack also uses execution() then you would get an infinite call loop, If HackTheHack uses call() (and Hack execution()), then it would just be calling the already weaved code of Hack - which is not what you want...

Comment: So, basically, there are a few limitations to AspectJ.. e.g. simply changing the `Hack` to use `execution` makes it *immortal* .. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Actually user @Yaneeve has presented a nice solution, but it has a few shortcomings, e.g. it

- only works for `call()`, not for `execution()`,
- needs reflection,
- needs `declare precedence`,
- needs to know the hack's class and package name beforehand (okay, that can be circumvented by using `*` in precedence declaration).

I have a more stable solution for you. I have modified the source code to be a little bit more realistic:

**Authenticator:**

The authenticator has a user database (hard-coded for simplicity) and actually compares users and passwords.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Authenticator {
    private static final Map<String, String> userDB = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        userDB.put("alice", "aaa");
        userDB.put("bob", "bbb");
        userDB.put("dave", "ddd");
        userDB.put("erin", "eee");
    }

    public boolean authenticate(String user, String pass) {
        return userDB.containsKey(user) && userDB.get(user).equals(pass);
    }
}
```

**Application:**

The application has an entry point and tries to authenticate a few users, printing the results:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
        System.out.println("Status: " + authenticator.authenticate("alice",  "aaa"));
        System.out.println("Status: " + authenticator.authenticate("bob",    "xxx"));
        System.out.println("Status: " + authenticator.authenticate("dave",   "ddd"));
        System.out.println("Status: " + authenticator.authenticate("erin",   "xxx"));
        System.out.println("Status: " + authenticator.authenticate("hacker", "xxx"));
    }
}
```

The application's output is as follows:

```
Status: true
Status: false
Status: true
Status: false
Status: false
```

**Authentication logger aspect:**

I want to add a *legal* aspect with an `around()` advice on the authentication method, just like the hacking aspect later.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Authenticator;

public aspect AuthenticationLogger {
    pointcut authentication(String user) :
        execution(boolean Authenticator.authenticate(String, String)) && args(user, *);

    boolean around(String user): authentication(user) {
        boolean result = proceed(user);
        System.out.println("[INFO] Authentication result for '" + user + "' = " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The output becomes:

```
[INFO] Authentication result for 'alice' = true
Status: true
[INFO] Authentication result for 'bob' = false
Status: false
[INFO] Authentication result for 'dave' = true
Status: true
[INFO] Authentication result for 'erin' = false
Status: false
[INFO] Authentication result for 'hacker' = false
Status: false
```

As you can see, "status" and "authentication result" are the same as long as the system was not hacked. No surprise here.

**Hacker aspect:**

Now let us hack the system. We can either always return true (positive authentication result) or always true for a certain user - whatever we like. We can even `proceed()` to the original call if we want to have its side effects, but we can still always return true, which is what we do in this example:

```java
package de.scrum_master.hack;

import de.scrum_master.app.Authenticator;

public aspect Hack {
    declare precedence : *, Hack;
    pointcut authentication() :
        execution(boolean Authenticator.authenticate(String, String));

    boolean around(): authentication() {
        System.out.println("Hack is active!");
        proceed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The output changes to:

```
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'alice' = true
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'bob' = true
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'dave' = true
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'erin' = true
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'hacker' = true
Status: true
```

Because the hacker aspect declares itself to be the last one in advice precedence (i.e. the innermost shell in a nested series of `proceed()` calls on the same joinpoint, its return value will be propagated up the call chain to the logger aspect, which is why the logger prints the already manipulated authentication result *after* it has received it from the inner aspect.

If we change the declaration to `declare precedence : Hack, *;` the output is as follows:

```
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'alice' = true
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'bob' = false
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'dave' = true
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'erin' = false
Status: true
Hack is active!
[INFO] Authentication result for 'hacker' = false
Status: true
```

I.e. the logger now logs the original result and propagates it up the call chain to the hacker aspect which can manipulate it at the very end because it is first in precedence and thus in control of the whole call chain. Having the final say is what a hacker would usually want, but in this case it would show a mismatch between what is logged (some authentications true, some false) and how the application actually behaves (always true because it was hacked).

**Anti hacker aspect:**

Now, last but not least we want to intercept advice executions and determine if they might come from possible hacker aspects. The good news is: AspectJ has a pointcut called `adviceexecution()` - nomen est omen. :-)

Advice execution join points have arguments which can be determined via `thisJoinPoint.getArgs()`. Unfortunately AspectJ cannot bind them to parameters via `args()`. If the intercepted advice is of `around()` type, the first `adviceexecution()` parameter will be an `AroundClosure` object. If you call the `run()` method upon this closure object and specify the correct arguments (which can be determined via `getState()`), the effect is that the actual advice body will not be executed but only implicitly `proceed()` will be called. This effectively disables the intercepted advice!

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure;

public aspect AntiHack {
    pointcut catchHack() :
        adviceexecution() && ! within(AntiHack) && !within(AuthenticationLogger);

    Object around() : catchHack() {
        Object[] adviceArgs = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        if (adviceArgs[0] instanceof AroundClosure) {
            AroundClosure aroundClosure = (AroundClosure) adviceArgs[0];
            Object[] closureState = aroundClosure.getState();
            System.out.println("[WARN] Disabling probable authentication hack: " + thisJoinPointStaticPart);
            try {
                return aroundClosure.run(closureState);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new SoftException(t);
            }
        }
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
[WARN] Disabling probable authentication hack: adviceexecution(boolean de.scrum_master.hack.Hack.around(AroundClosure))
[INFO] Authentication result for 'alice' = true
Status: true
[WARN] Disabling probable authentication hack: adviceexecution(boolean de.scrum_master.hack.Hack.around(AroundClosure))
[INFO] Authentication result for 'bob' = false
Status: false
[WARN] Disabling probable authentication hack: adviceexecution(boolean de.scrum_master.hack.Hack.around(AroundClosure))
[INFO] Authentication result for 'dave' = true
Status: true
[WARN] Disabling probable authentication hack: adviceexecution(boolean de.scrum_master.hack.Hack.around(AroundClosure))
[INFO] Authentication result for 'erin' = false
Status: false
[WARN] Disabling probable authentication hack: adviceexecution(boolean de.scrum_master.hack.Hack.around(AroundClosure))
[INFO] Authentication result for 'hacker' = false
Status: false
```

As you can see,

- the result is now the same as without the hacker aspect, i.e. we effectively disabled it,
- it was not necessary to know the hacker aspect's class or package name, but in our `catchHack()` pointcut we specify a white list of known aspects which should *not* be disabled, i.e. run unchanged,
- we are only targeting `around()` advice because `before()` and `after()` advice have signatures without `AroundClosure`s.

**Anti hacker advice with target method heuristics:**

Unfortunately I found no way to determine the method targeted by the around closure, so there is no exact way to limit the anti hacker advice's scope to advice specifically targeting the method we want to protect against hacking. In this example we can narrow down the scope by heuristically checking the content of the array returned by `AroundClosure.getState()` which consists of

- the advice's target object as the first parameter (we need to check if it is an `Authenticator` instance),
- the target method call's parameters (for `Authenticator.authenticate()` there must be two `String`s).

This knowledge is undocumented (just like the contents of advice execution's arguments), I found out by trial and error. Anyway, this modification enables the heuristics:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure;

import de.scrum_master.app.Authenticator;

public aspect AntiHack {
    pointcut catchHack() :
        adviceexecution() && ! within(AntiHack) && !within(AuthenticationLogger);

    Object around() : catchHack() {
        Object[] adviceArgs = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        if (adviceArgs[0] instanceof AroundClosure) {
            AroundClosure aroundClosure = (AroundClosure) adviceArgs[0];
            Object[] closureState = aroundClosure.getState();
            if (closureState.length == 3
                    && closureState[0] instanceof Authenticator
                    && closureState[1] instanceof String
                    && closureState[2] instanceof String
            ) {
                System.out.println("[WARN] Disabling probable authentication hack: " + thisJoinPointStaticPart);
                try {
                    return aroundClosure.run(closureState);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    throw new SoftException(t);
                }
            }
        }
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

The output stays the same as above, but if there are multiple advice in the hacker aspect or even multiple hacker aspects you will see the difference. This version is narrowing down the scope. If you want this or not is up to you. I suggest you use the simpler version. In that case you only need to be careful to update the pointcut to always have an up to date whitelist.

Sorry for the lenghty answer, but I found the problem fascinating and tried to explain my solution as good as possible.

Comment: Excellent answer. Those who stop reading after the accepted answer are missing a treat!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the proceed() call. What you probably want is something like this:

```
public aspect Hack {

    pointcut authHack(String user, String pass): call(* Authenticator.authenticate(String,String)) && args(user,pass);

    boolean around(String user, String pass): authHack(user,pass) {
        out("$$$ " + user + ":" + pass + " $$$");
        boolean result = proceed(user,pass);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: *to write a second aspect that cancels/disables the authHack advice* not to fix the Hack

Comment: @Queequeg I fail to understand you downed my answer, since: 1. you're not the one who asked, 2. This solves the problem of being able to authenticate, 3. you provided no better alternative

Comment: @anjosc, please don't get insulted, just note that as Queequeg wrote, your answer misses the whole point of the question, which as she says is "to write a second aspect that cancels/disables the authHack advice not to fix the Hack". BTW, from personal experience, it might be a different person that had downvoted your answer than the one who had been nice enough to comment on why it is a bad one. Best of luck here at SO

Comment: @anjosc The down-vote is to push the answer down, because it's not related to the question. No offence intended :)